# Colorbox loads only once - Uncaught TypeError: $.colorbox is not a function(…)

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox, gmaps.js

Ok, first thing would be to check if path to colorbox JS file ir correct and if reference the colorbox file is after the jquery file. They both are!

The real mystery comes from fact that colorbox works on first time but the the error appears. And the funniest is that it used to work but then suddenly didn`t.

Here is the function that calls for colorbox:

```
function loadJsonMap(map, data){
    var markers_data = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val){
        if (val.latitude != undefined && val.longitude != undefined) {
            markers_data.push({
                lat : val.latitude,
                lng : val.longitude,
                details : {
                holder_id : val.holder_id
                },
                click : function(e){
                    if(e.details.holder_id !== undefined){
                        var url = baseurl + 'index.php/products/colorbox/' + e.details.holder_id;
                        $.colorbox({
                            open : true,
                            href : url,
                            iframe : false,
                            innerWidth : 400,
                            innerHeight : 400,
                            close : 'Aizvert'
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    map.addMarkers(markers_data);
}
```

This function is used to add marker on Gmap. Two days ago I could click how many markers I wanted and every time a new colorbox would show up but now I get to do that only once before getting error on `$.colorbox({` line. I am 99% sure that I haven`t changed anything associated with this. Really do not know how to understand this error.

**UPDATE:**
The error seems to be caused by colorbox but affects jQuery. After first colorbox is opened every jQuery call is not a function. Now I get error on :

```
$(function() {
          $('#contact-link').on('click', function() {
            if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
              deselect($(this), 'contactpop');               
            } else {
              $(this).addClass('selected');
              $('.contactpop').slideFadeToggle();
            }
            return false;
          });
        });

        $.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
          return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, 'fast', easing, callback);
        };
```

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slideFadeToggle is not a function(…)

but before clicking marker and opening colorbox I could call `slideFadeToggle` multiple times...

Comment: What is the exact error that the console displays? I think the syntax is `$(selector).colorbox(options)`. -- So try adding the selector of the element you want to get colorbox-ed.

Comment: scripts.js:155 Uncaught TypeError: $.colorbox is not a function(…) 
I added this selector but same result. The thing is that $.colorbox (options) does work but only once. But the fact that it works once means that there is no problem with either including it correctly or seleting...